# Value transfer between classes

Tags: java, android, class, object

I've 3 classes and thoose are

A : MainActivity

B : Model

C : Controller

I'm trying to passing values between them. I've get-set methods in Model class for each variable. What I am trying to do is set values on MainActivity then process that values via some methods on Controller class and set results of that methods to Model class again. When I check that set variable on Controller class I'm getting null value. I'm defining public static object of Model class on MainActivity for setting values.

```
public class MainActivity {
    public static Model model;
    private Controller controller;
    onCreate(){
        model=new Model();
        controller = new Controller ();
        model.setpName("someString");
        controller.doSth();
    }
}
```

and in my Model class

```
public class Model {
    private String pName;
    public String getpName(){return this.pName;}
    public void setpName(String pName){this.pName=pName;}
    private String pResult;
    public String getpResult() {
        return this.pResult;
    }
    public void setpResult(String pResult){
        this.pResult=pResult;
    } 
}
```

and in my Controller class

```
public class Controller {
    public Model model;
    public void doSth(){
        model = new Model(); 
        System.out.println(model.getpName+"");

    }
}
```

When I check that

```
System.out.println(model.getpName+"");
```

on Controller class,
it returns with null value.
What am I doing wrong ? 
How to get the value that what I set on MainActivity ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your controller has an un instantiated Model.. at least according to your code above

Comment: sorry I forgot to wrote it here. I did it actually

Comment: please update your code in the question

Comment: Maybe your controllers constructor should take the model

Comment: Can u write your suggestion as an answer with some sample code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace your code like this;

```
    public class Controller {
    public Model model;
    public void doSth(){
        model = new Model(); 
        model = MainActivity.model;
        System.out.println(model.getpName+"");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Model is never injected in your Controller so it's normal. You should have something like the following line somewhere in your MainActivity class

```
controller.setModel(model)
```

And could I mention that the naming of your methods is not really good. It should be

```
setPName()
getPName()
...
```

With CAPITAL letters after the action :)

Comment: Actually those are sample codes from my app. But yea you're right about that ugly names!:) Now I'm gonna try that inject thing then let you know!.

Comment: Can u explain it with some sample codes. I think I couldn't get what did u mean?

Answer (score 1):

First, your controller class doesn't have a getpResult() function. Did you mean to call the doSth() function ?

Also, the model variable in your controller class is never initialized. When you do

```
model.getpName()+"blabla";
```

you should get a NullPointerException.

Last thing, just to be sure, your call to

```
System.out.println(model.getpName+"");
```

is made **after** calling the onCreate() method of your MainActivity class, right ? Otherwise it's normal that the value is null.

Comment: You're right I'm gonna edit it. and I need that value for some other methods in my controller class.

Answer (score 0):

You did not instanciate  your model. So your pName is null.

Edit for more explanation:

When you call doSth()

```
public void doSth(){
        model = new Model(); 
        System.out.println(model.getpName+"");

    }
```

You create a new model and its pName is null because of model = new Model();

You can use a constructor for your controller which takes model as a parameter or you can set model to your controller with a setter method. You should not use model = new Model(); in your doSth.

Comment: I explained with sample. You can check it above.